# Detecting backwards incompatible API changes for releases

Tags: javascript, api, compatibility, release

I manage an open-source JS library that is developed on by hundreds of people. Is there an easy, automated, way to determine if a particular marked release is has a backwards incompatible API change? I see something similar for Java, [Java API Compliance Checker](http://ispras.linuxbase.org/index.php/Java_API_Compliance_Checker).

More detail on the code base: We have both an internal version and an external version of the code base. We just occasionally push the internal version "over the wall" to GitHub. At that point, we'd like to determine if the newly created external version has API changes that could break users.

Yes, we could just ask developers to try to keep note if they check in backwards incompatible changes, but this is error prone and would be much better if it was automated.

Comment: Write a test suite against the public API; if you break a test, you break compatibility.

Comment: Push onto a middle stage test server first?

Comment: I guess I was asking for more automated tooling as our code base is very large.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do is, is with unit tests. You write your tests to how you expect your API to work. If your API changes in an incompatible way, your test will break, and you know the change is backwards-incompatible.